# How can I see more of the Java stack trace when an exception occurs in JLink?

Tags: java, message-coding

If I call into Java code via `` JLink` ``, and there is an uncaught exception, Mathematica produces a `Java::excptn` message, and prints a short snippet of the stack trace (3 or 4 lines). Unfortunately I can't decipher from the few lines that it prints what's going on.

> Can I make Mathematica print the entire stack trace when an exception is thrown in `` JLink` ``?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Mathematica* usually shows all of the stack trace elements that are due to user code.  It omits stack frames that belongs to *JLink* itself.  This is rarely a problem but, as we shall see, there is a small possibility that we could lose some frames of interest.

**Example**

Before we talk about the missing frames, let's look at an example.  The following code is contrived to throw an exception from a fairly deep call stack:

```
Needs["JLink`"]
InstallJava[];

JavaNew["javax.script.ScriptEngineManager"] @
  getEngineByName["JavaScript"] @
  eval["throw 'bad news!'"]
```

[image: stack trace]

We can see that many stack frames are shown.  In fact, all of the frames related to our code are shown.  The outermost frame (`AbstractScriptEngine.eval`) corresponds directly to our `eval[...]` expression.

However, there is a subtle clue that some frames are missing from this trace.  Notice the last line of the causative exception, where it says "... 13 more".  This implies that the main stack trace should have 13 lines, but we only see three.  Which frames are missing?

**Missing Frames**

When `JLink` assembles a message reporting a stack trace, it quietly omits any frames that it thinks belong to `JLink` itself.  In the case at hand, this amounts to the ten missing frames.  We can peek at the `JLink` frames like this:

```
JavaBlock @ Module[{s}
, s = JavaNew["java.io.StringWriter"]
; JavaNew["java.lang.RuntimeException", "bad news!"] @
    printStackTrace[JavaNew["java.io.PrintWriter", s]]
; s @ toString[]
]

(*
java.lang.RuntimeException: bad news!
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.wolfram.jlink.ClassRecord.callBestCtor(ObjectHandler.java:749)
    at com.wolfram.jlink.ObjectHandler.callCtor(ObjectHandler.java:125)
    at com.wolfram.jlink.KernelLinkImpl.callJava(KernelLinkImpl.java:942)
    at com.wolfram.jlink.KernelLinkImpl.handleCallPacket(KernelLinkImpl.java:628)
    at com.wolfram.jlink.KernelLinkImpl.handlePacket(KernelLinkImpl.java:303)
    at com.wolfram.jlink.Reader.run(Reader.java:154)
*)
```

This code captures a stack trace and converts it to a string before `JLink` can get its hands on it.  It shows us ten JLink-related frames.

**What Frames Will Be Omitted?**

The code for `JLink` is shipped with the *Mathematica* distribution.  We can inspect it to see exactly which frames are dropped:

```
{ $InstallationDirectory
, "SystemFiles","Links","JLink","Source","Java","com","wolfram","jlink","Utils.java"
} // FileNameJoin // FilePrint

(*
// ... snip ... 442 lines omitted ...
static String createExceptionMessage(Throwable t) {
    // ... snip ...
    if (t instanceof java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException)
        t = ((java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException) t).getTargetException();
    // ... snip ...
        if (line.indexOf("at com.wolfram.jlink") == -1 &&
            line.indexOf("at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke") == -1 &&
            line.indexOf("at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl") == -1 &&
            line.indexOf("at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl") == -1 &&
            line.indexOf("at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1") == -1 &&
            line.indexOf("at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2") == -1)
            linesToKeep.add(line);
    }
    // ... snip ...
*)
```

We can see that *JLink* will drop not only any frames sourced from the package `com.wolfram.jlink`, but also from various components related to Java reflection.  Furthermore, it quietly unwraps `InvocationTargetException`.  Almost all of the time, none of these missing stack frames will matter for stack trace diagnosis.  But in the unusual circumstance that the component being debugged uses reflection above and beyond that used by *JLink*, then some useful frames might be missing.

**But I Need Those Frames!!!**

In the unlikely and unfortunate event that the missing frames are required for debugging, some possible strategies to recover them include:

- Adjust the target Java code, or the *Mathematica* code that invokes it, to capture the full stack trace before *JLink* sees it, along the lines of what was done in one of the examples above.
- Attach a remote debugging session to the Java process (e.g. using [IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) or [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org)) and set a breakpoint at a convenient location.
- Attach [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) to the Java process and try to get a thread stack dump at an opportune moment.
- Build a new version of *JLink.jar* from the supplied source, with suitable modifications to the function *createExceptionMessage* (not recommended, almost certainly overkill).

These are likely ordered by increasing ambition.  Details concerning any of these options are well out of scope for this forum.